# replace #define macro with a consteval/exprs for non static member using 'this'

Tags: c++, logging, macros, c++17, c++20

I am wondering if there is a way to convert a macro with a `consteval` when using a `this` pointer in a static member.

for e.g consider just a debug logger macro:

```
#define LOGD(msg) loggerDebug(typeid(*this).name(), __func__, msg)
```

is there a way to have that kind of macro converted into a `consteval`?
for e.g., this won't compile

```
consteval void LOGD_(const char* msg) { loggerDebug(typeid(*this).name(), __func__, msg); }
```

the only way looks like it is required to pass the this pointer to the counterpart of consteval, forcing again to have a macro that it will do it automatically, so no real point having a const eval in this specific case.

Is there a way without using macro to define the above macro?

Comment: Please note that `typeid(*this).name()` might not give you a user-friendly name.

Comment: As for your function, `__func__` will return the name of the `LOGD_` function. To avoid that see [`std::source_location`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/source_location) which was added in C++20. Won't solve the `this` problem though.

Comment: Hum, what is an `loggerDebug`? Can you provide practical examples showing what you're trying to do?

Comment: What compile time (consteval) debug logging is supposed to go on?

Comment: You might have more success with a function template to inject the type. `this` is a runtime concept that's not going to fly in consteval. Also __func__ is probably not going to be what you expect.

Comment: loggerDebug is just a function printing on stdout the 'msg' including from which class/method has been triggered

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude the `std::source_location` might be a good alternative fit, it won't be the same but it should be a good enough alternative.... thanks for that tip.